# Showing total rep for a team?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, old-teams

So far the teams are great, but we StackOverflowers are a competitive bunch.

What would be great is if more rep was shown on the team page. For example, would it be possible to have:

- Total rep for a team?
- Global ranking for a team compared to other teams?
- Rep for each member?

[image]

Comment: Hopefully "ranking" is something you would opt-in for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/teams/102/loungec would be at the top forever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely *in some form*, but maybe not be at the very top of the Team page.

We do want to surface Q&A activity on Teams, perhaps on a separate tab (which would be the natural location for reputation, top posts, top tags, etc. to be shown).